# Isn't Google App Engine suppose to be more expensive than Google Kubernetes engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I had my app in the app engine(Flex). But it's costing a lot with no traffic yet!
I decided to move that to Kubernetes Engine which utilizes the compute engine.
Another reason I moved to Kubernetes because I wanted to run docker container services like Memcached that come with an added cost in App Engine Flex.

If you are tempted to ask why am not using App Engine Standard which is economical, that's because I couldn't find any easy way if at all there's any for running services like GDAL & Memcached.

I thought Kubernetes should be a cheaper option, but what I am seeing is the opposite.
I have even had to change the machine type to g1-small from N1...

Am I missing something?
Any ideas on how to reduce cost in Kubernetes / compute engine instances?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the documentation [GKE Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing) and [App Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-pricing):

> GKE clusters accrue a management fee of $0.10 per cluster per hour,
> irrespective of cluster size or topology. One zonal (single-zone or
> multi-zonal) cluster per billing account is free.
>
> GKE uses Compute Engine instances for [worker nodes in the cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#nodes). **You
> are billed for each of those instances** according to [Compute Engine's
> pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing), until the nodes are deleted. Compute Engine resources are
> billed **on a per-second basis with a one-minute minimum usage cost**.

and

> Apps running in the flexible environment are deployed to virtual
> machine types that you specify. These virtual machine resources are
> **billed on a per-second basis with a 1 minute minimum usage cost**.

> **Billing for the memory resource includes the memory your app uses plus
> the memory that the runtime itself needs to run your app**. This means
> your memory usage and costs can be higher than the maximum memory you
> request for your app.

So, both GAE Flex and GKE cluster are "billed on a per-second basis with a 1 minute minimum usage cost".

**To estimate usage cost** in advance you can use [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator), also you can use it to estimate how changing parameters of your cluster can help you to reduce cost and which solution is more cost effective.

In addition, please have a look at the documentation [Best practices for running cost-optimized Kubernetes applications on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-for-running-cost-effective-kubernetes-applications-on-gke).